# Why request.getParamether don't work in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

Hello i can't get any value from a from in my index.jsp file. I'm using tomcat7, after running index.jsp and clicking send button nothing happen. System.out.prinln() print nothinig or null ;(

index.jsp

```
%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form acton="addnewtask.jsp" method="post" >
        <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

addnewtask.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>


<%
    String s  = request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(s);
%>
```

Do you know what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I suppose you forgot to assign a `name` attribute to your `<input>` tag.

Comment: And it should be `action=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line allows you to get a parameter with its **name** not its **id** :

```
 String s  = request.getParameter("name");
```

Add a name to your input and correct the typo of the attribute action of your form :

```
  <form action="addnewtask.jsp" method="post" >
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
  <form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s  = request.getParameter("xyz");
```

Add a name to your input box

```
  <form action="addnewtask.jsp" method="post" >
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="xyz" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
  <form>
```